# Total number of sites seems incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange

Currently, Stackexchange claims 53 Q&A sites. I count 55, including MSO. I'll grant that MSO ought not to be counted, given that we don't count the other metas. But that still leaves me at 54, not 53.

Count for yourself: https://stackexchange.com/sites

(I counted the occurrences of the word 'ago' on the page, I didn't do it manually.)

Comment: Those stats are probably cached heavily -- if a couple of new sites were launched recently, they may not have been picked up by the calculation.

Comment: I don't buy it. The number was 51 before two sites launched this week. And the number of accounts has kept up with the recent millionth account, I don't see why the number of sites would be more heavily cached than the number of accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "53 Q&A sites" don't include [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com).

Comment: Although we can make intelligent guesses.. just for clarity, why exactly?

Comment: @Daniel None of the Meta sites are included (otherwise, the number would be much higher, as an example). Not sure what to say for Stack Apps, though.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I missed stackapps, thanks.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo, @GraceNote My reason would be that they aren't counting those sites that answer questions that wouldn't exist if SE didn't exist. Or, they count the sites that answer questions that people google for.