# Update StackExchange site count to reflect recent SE inductees

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Total number of sites seems incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94495/total-number-of-sites-seems-incorrect)

The [StackExchange "about" page](https://stackexchange.com/about) prominently purports that it is a network of "**59** question and answer sites," but in reality it's now a network of **61** such sites.  Let's not leave our new friends [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)  and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) out of the count. :o)

Also, on the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites), the "Network Stats" blurb lists **59** as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has come up before, but Meta Stack Overflow does not count, nor does Stack Apps.

So the count is correct as-is afaik -- the Stack Exchange 2.0 network is all *non-meta Q&A sites*.  Stack Apps is a special kind of meta site, where we talk about apps and the API.

Comment: Just replace the count with the latest Google Chrome version: ∞

Comment: @ckittel updated for realz...it's because MSO and StackApps are not counted

Comment: Maybe the Network stats blurp should list "2 meta sites" (or 62 if we include the site specific ones and the discussion site for Area 51?), too?