# How many sites are there on Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

In different places I see a different number of Stack Exchange sites:

- http://meta.stackexchange.com

  > [image: 162-163]
- http://stackexchange.com

  > [image: 164]

I suppose this number should be the same everywhere.

P.S. Question in the title is not a real question in which I'm interested. It's just a title for bug report, where I would like to show that count should be same for whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I counted 165 sites? Caching error or human error?

Comment: Maybe caching. [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) went public **today**.

Comment: Long standing issue: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94495/total-number-of-sites-seems-incorrect), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103186/update-stackexchange-site-count-to-reflect-recent-se-inductees), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239791/tour-shows-that-se-consist-of-127-communities-and-help-center-shows-128)

Comment: Not related, [same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271749/312043)

Comment: @PythonMaster still have same numbers ... seems not a cache problem.

Comment: this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325865/254520) has a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1019093/how-many-stackexchange-non-meta-sites-are-there) to calculate the up-to-date number of non-meta sites

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now it's 175 sites...

Just go to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), then search for the keyword "site age"

> [image: site list]

The list doesn't contain [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), so you need to add 1 to get the final count of sites on Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: The bug is that the total number of sites differ depending on where you look. The bug report doesn't need a new answer every time a site graduated or is taken down. That is not the point of this specific question, which is also pointed out by the OP in a PS at the end of their question.

Comment: @rene the answer does contain a nice trick which I also used to count the sites.

Answer (score 5):

So... there's currently 165 sites since the Internet of Things SE just went up today (thanks @Helmar). The text should be updated at the same time for all of the examples you have given to 165. If we are counting `stackexchange.com` to be a site, the text should read 166*:

> A list of all 165* sites Stack Exchange sites

and

> Meta Stack Exchange is part of the StackExchange network of 165* Q&A communities.

Of course, only a Stack Exchange employee can verify and/or apply this