# Extra items in the achievement list if question's title has been changed

Tags: bug, ios-app

My [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289233/339911) has been renamed. After that iOS app shows extra items in the achievements list:

> [image: app]

Web achievements list contains only one rep item per question in separate time interval:

> [image: web]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)