# Add alias URL for posts timeline

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks, timeline

I know that to view timeline of the post I need to manually change an URL in the browser, e.g. [How many sites are there on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289233/how-many-sites-are-there-on-stack-exchange) has an URL:

> ```
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289233/how-many-sites-are-there-on-stack-exchange
> ```

To access the timeline I need to replace `questions` with `posts` and `how-many-sites-are-there-on-stack-exchange` with `timeline`.

Since post's *id* is enough to uniquely refer to a post (no matter if it’s an answer or a question), my request would be to allow one to change only the last part of the URL to `timeline` to open the timeline page.

Long story short, I would like to use following URL to access the timeline of discussed question:

> ```
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289233/timeline
> ```

For now such link opens a quesion as if `timeline` tail of the URL is not in action.

One problem case might be only if question title is *"timeline"*, but since question title must be at least 15 characters long - this case doesn't make sense to consider.

P.S. If you will decline my request, please add a user friendly link to time line as suggested on [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/339911). :)

Comment: Agreed, and additionally, add anchors for revisions: http://foo.stackexchange.com/q/NNNNN/timeline#4 would be revision 4 in that post's timeline.

Comment: I made a chrome extension so that a `timeline` link shows up right next to `share` and `edit`, which points toward the `posts/xxxxxxx/timeline` link, lol.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Anything on the `/questions` path always displays a question. It does not make sense to modify that path to add an exception just to make the timeline easier to access. Displaying information about and performing actions to posts is why the `/posts` path exists - so that the `/questions` path isn't cluttered with other things.

I get you want a link there, and one of the main blockers has always been the amount of space in the links below the post. *You* may enjoy having another link there, but more links can irritate other users. Because of a user script I use, my links section below a post actually looks like this:

[image: Links!]

I personally enjoy having all the tools there; others find it way too cluttered.

Comment: Probably adding a settings to profile is suitable for not irritate other users if such links will not be shown by default.

Comment: We're not fans of adding settings, and intentionally keep the amount of settings to a minimum. Adding a setting for this is probably the last thing that would ever happen.

Comment: I thought the last is adding a link under post's body :)