# How many meta websites exist in the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

I wonder how many meta websites exist in the Stack Exchange network?

The list of 176 sites show only Meta Stack Exchange, but I know we also have Meta Stack Overflow, for example.

Comment: Related [Total number of sites seems incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94495)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every site has a per-site meta with two exceptions: Stack Apps and this main meta site.

Assuming N to be the number of sites listed in https://stackexchange.com/sites, this makes in total (N-2) per site metas + 1 main meta = (N-1) metas.

Note that Area 51, the site where new Stack Exchange communities are organized, [also has a meta site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), though Area 51 is not listed in [the official list of SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Taking this into account, we get N metas.

Comment: "N" is part of the correct answer, because there are a few developer sites not for users; with associated meta (and +1); Whether the answer is "N-1", "N+1", or simply "N", as a result, is open for debate.

Answer (score 5):

You can query the StackApps API for the correct number, taking into account that Area 51 isn't present in the API.

Run the code snippet to get the current numbers.

```js
(function() {

  var backoff = 0;
  
  function buildUrl(api, query) {
    var qs = Object.keys(query||{})
      .reduce((acc,val) => { 
        return (acc===''?'?'+val:acc+'&'+val) + '=' + query[val]
      },'');
    return 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/' + api + qs;
  }

  function error(txt) {
    document.getElementById('error').textContent=txt;
  }
 
  function callApi(api, query, reqBody) {
    query.key = 'QGv6M2Kx2ftIozePLXl6nA((';
    function exec(resolve,reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var init = {};
        if ( reqBody !== undefined) {
          init.method = 'POST';
          init.body = new FormData();
          Object.keys(reqBody).forEach((v) => {
            init.body.set(v, reqBody[v]);
          });
          Object.keys(query).forEach((v) => {
            init.body.set(v, query[v]);
          });
          query = {};
        }
        fetch(buildUrl(api, query), init).then((data) => {
          if (!data.ok) error(data.status);
          data.json().then((data) => {
            backoff = data.backoff || 0;
            resolve(data.items);    
          });
        });
      }, backoff * 1000);
    }
    return new Promise(exec);
  }

  function SitesViewModel() {
    this.categories = ko.observableArray();  
  }

  var svm = new SitesViewModel();
  
  function getSites() {
    callApi('sites', {filter:'!*L1-85AFW7Zla(De', pagesize:500}).then((items)=> {
      items.forEach((item) => {
        var handled = false;
        for(var i=0; i<svm.categories().length; i++) {
           var cat = svm.categories()[i];
           if (cat.name === item.site_type) {
             cat.count++;
             handled = true;
           } 
        }
        if (handled === false) {
          svm.categories().push({ name:item.site_type, count: 1 });
        }
       });
       ko.applyBindings(svm);     
    });
  }

  getSites();  
 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="error"></div>
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Category</th><th>Count</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: categories'>
  <tr>
  <td data-bind='text:name'></td>
  <td data-bind='text:count'></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```